# Swift LinkedList resulting in segmentation fault

Tags: swift, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Just to learn more and practice some Swift, I attempted a LinkedList implementation. It appears to work as I am able to add and remove some integers and verify these two operations are working as expected.

However, at the end of this main program, when I re-initialize the `nums` variable which is an instance of `LinkedList<Int>`, a segmentation fault occurs... why and how to fix?

```
import Foundation

var start = DispatchTime.now()
var nums = LinkedList<Int>()
for i in 1...100000 {
  nums.insert(i)
}
var end = DispatchTime.now()
print(end.rawValue - start.rawValue)

// reinitialize causes segmentation fault, why?
nums = LinkedList<Int>()
```

The complete class is below, and it is also executable here on Replit:
https://replit.com/@J_W_Clark/SwiftLinkedList-SegFault

```
class LinkedList<T: Comparable> : CustomStringConvertible {
  private var head: Node<T>?
  private var tail: Node<T>?
  private var size = 0

  private class Node<T: Comparable> : CustomStringConvertible {
    var next: Node?
    var value: T

    init(_ value: T) {
      self.value = value
    }

    public var description: String { return "\(self.value)" }
  }

  func insert(_ value: T) {
    if size < 1 {
      head = Node(value)
      tail = head
    } else {
      let newNode = Node(value)
      tail!.next = newNode // add new node to tail
      tail = newNode // newNode becomes new tail
    }
    size += 1
  }

  func remove(_ value: T) {
    if size < 1 { return } // head is nil

    // head is not nil
    if head!.value == value {
      if head!.next == nil {
        head = nil
      } else {
        head = head!.next
      }
      size -= 1
      return
    }

    var node = head!.next
    var previous = head!
    while node != nil {
      if node!.value == value {
        if node!.next == nil { // the last one
          tail = previous
          previous.next = nil
        } else {
          previous.next = node!.next
        }
        return
      }
      previous = node!
      node = node!.next
    }
  }

  public var description: String {
    var text = "["
    var node = head
    while node != nil {
      text += "\(node!.value)"
      node = node!.next
      if node != nil { text += ", " }
    }
    return text + "]"
  }
}v
```

Comment: This is only reproducible when you turn optimisations off. Try compiling with optimisation (option `-O`).

Comment: This is how it is compiled on Replit `swiftc -o main LinkedList.swift main.swift` but I see your point - if I remove the -o then it does not reproduce the error. At least that's a new direction to explore. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can specify the `-O` option (note that this is different from `-o`) on Replit, so try compiling with `-O` on your local computer.

Comment: Since it's `nums = LinkedList<Int>()` that's causing the segfault, I'm guessing something's gone wrong when deallocating all those 100,000 nodes in a cascading manner. The optimised version might be able to "do something about it" (I don't know what).

Comment: In `remove` you have a case where `tail` is not set to `nil` when `head` is set to `nil`. I don't see the connection with your script (as `remove` is not called), but it is an issue. Also, the link to replit does not seem to work. Did you remove the snippet?

Comment: I fixed the replit link. Good point about tail.